# How did the letters pass through the chimney if it was obstructed by the electric fireplace?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, the fireplace of Number 4, Privet Drive, has been replaced by an electric fire. Because of that the Weasleys had quite a problem to get into the house through the floo network. However, the letters in *Philosopher's Stone* didn't have a problem at all when flying through the fireplace:

> Next moment, thirty or forty letters came pelting out of the fireplace like bullets.

I'm wondering how they got there? Did the fireplace get replaced by an electric fireplace later and they got pushed into the chimney? Or did they appear somehow *below* the blockade of the chimney? How did the letters get to Number 4 anyway? I mean, the first letter probably was transported by the normal post, but as there is no post on Sundays, this can't have been the case later.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here - the fireplace was a normal fireplace in _Philosopher's Stone_, wasn't it? It got replaced later. Why would the letters have a problem with something that isn't there, something that would be added 4 years later?

Comment: Also -- it's magic. ;)

Comment: @Gallifreyan so was it replaced later? I don't remember this was mentioned​.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're saying. I seem to remember something being mentioned when the Weasleys crashed in the fireplace about it being a recent addition to the room, but I don't think I can find a reference now.

Comment: *Loud bangings and scrapings were coming from behind the Dursleys' boarded-up fireplace, which had a fake coal fire plugged in front of it.*... I can't think of a quote off the top of my head, but I believe they boarded it up in an attempt to stop the letters in PS (before resorting to going to an island in the middle of nowhere etc...)

Comment: ^ What Jon Clements said.

Comment: @JonClements I doubt it, as it is described quite clearly that they fled from the room, packed their stuff and drove away.

Comment: Umm yeah... *Something came whizzing down the kitchen chimney as he spoke and caught him sharply on the back of the head. Next moment, thirty or forty letters came pelting out of the fireplace like bullets. The Dursleys ducked, but Harry leapt into the air trying to catch one* [...] *"That does it," said Uncle Vernon, trying to speak calmly but pulling great tufts out of his mustache at the same time. "I want you all back here in five minutes ready to leave. We're going away. Just pack some clothes. No arguments!"*

Comment: Seems that someone pondered this 12 years ago: http://alt.fan.harry-potter.narkive.com/l7lX1rDq/the-dursleys-fireplace-book-4-spoilers#post6

Comment: So it looks like the letters came from the chimney in the kitchen, and Mr Weasley got the wrong fireplace connected to the floo network and tried to get in via the boarded up fireplace with the electric fire in the living room...

Comment: @JonClements still seems rather weird to me, but it's possible.

Comment: [Whenever you notice something like that, a wizard did it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVgVB3qsySQ)

Comment: Related: [Why do the Dursleys have two fireplaces in their home?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/150700/70236)

Comment: *How did the letters pass thorough the chimney?* Very well, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fireplace that the letters came through in *The Philosopher's Stone* was in the kitchen:

> Something came whizzing down the kitchen chimney as he spoke and caught him sharply on the back of the head. Next moment, thirty or forty letters came pelting out of the fireplace like bullets.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* - p.35 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 3, *The Letters from No One*

This fireplace was clearly not boarded up.

However, the Weasleys managed to turn up behind the fireplace in the living room:

> From the other side of the living-room door came the sounds of the three Dursleys scrambling, panic-stricken, across the room.
>
> [...]
>
> Loud bangings and scrapings were coming from behind the Dursleys' boarded-up fireplace, which had a fake coal fire plugged in front of it.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - p.42 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 4, *Back to The Burrow*

This is a totally different fireplace to the one in the kitchen, which remains unobstructed into the days of *The Order of the Phoenix*

> WHOOSH. With a clattering, a whirring of wings and a soft fall of dust, a fourth owl came shooting out of the kitchen fireplace.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.36 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 2, *A Peck of Owls*

---

> How did the letters get to Number 4 anyway? I mean, the first letter probably was transported by the normal post, but as there is no post on Sundays, this can't have been the case later.

(Strictly speaking it's one question at a time on this stack, but as it's a one-word (or one-name) answer ...)

Hagrid

> 'I'm - er - not supposed ter do magic, strictly speakin'. I was allowed ter do a bit ter follow yeh an' get yeh letters to yeh an' stuff - one o' the reasons I was so keen ter take on the job -'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* - p.48 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 4, *The Keeper of the Keys*